# DataGrid not showing data

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid in my UserControl and i am filling it dynamically . Using this code :

```
     conn.Open()
    cmd = New OdbcCommand("select dum,I_name from tbl_items where H=1", conn)
    Dim da As New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable("head")
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgv_itemHead.ItemsSource = New DataView(dt)
    conn.Close()
```

It dose not show data i only shows two lines in it . i have one row in my table ..
Why it is happening ? how to solve this problem

Comment: Were there any columns in datatable? Have `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true` for your datagrid?

Comment: can you post your connection string code

Comment: DataView view = dt.DefaultView;
dgv_itemHead.ItemsSource = view;